# MySQL database query using multiple table JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm using a MySQL non normalized database with duplicate records.

One of the tables contains a lookup in 2 different columns.

Here is a sample of two tables

TABLE A

id1  id2

202  866

811  202

423  202

202  609

202  335

TABLE B

id   value

202  hot

542  cold

609  warm

866  humid

RESULTS

202 hot

542 cold

609 warm

866 humid

The query should lookup all records where there is a matching record in column id1, then lookup all matching records based on id2.

In other words, find all records in table B if there is a match on id1, then find the additional record based on id2 or vice versa.

I've spent 3 days trying to muddle my way through this mess.

Any database gurus might have a simple approach to writing this SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `UNION`, e.g.:

```
SELECT ta.id1 AS id, tb.value as value
FROM tableA ta JOIN tableb TB ON ta.id1 = tb.id

UNION

SELECT ta.id2 AS id, tb.value as value
FROM tableA ta JOIN tableb TB ON ta.id2 = tb.id
```

Comment: `UNION` will only return distinct rows. `UNION` = `UNION DISTINCT`